# External JS file works perfectly well in Firefox but not in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

Here's the code right away in my separate JS file:

```
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        if ($('.span4').css("left") == "0px") {
            $('.span4').css("left", "auto");
        } else if ($('.span4').css("left") < "0px") {
            $('.span4').css('left', -$(window).scrollLeft() - 20);
        }
    })
});
$(function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {

        if ($(window).width() >= "1130") {
        $('.span4').css("left", "auto");
        }
    })
});
```

This perfectly works well in Firefox but in IE (facepalm).... But if i place this code inline in the html it works well in both IE and Firefox... why you IE :(

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors in IE? Also, you can put all your code in one `$(function() { });` block.

Comment: What's the error message from IE?

Comment: no error messages in IE... this javascript code is just for adjusting the left width during resizing and scrolling of the window...

Comment: I don't know if it's the cause of the problem, but (a) you're assigning an integer to `left` on line 7, and (b) you're comparing a fetched `css()` length with an exact string including a unit. Both of these are unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

Could be any number of things. Maybe it's not being invoked in IE. Try the following

```
$(function () {
$(window).scroll(function () {

    if ($('.span4').css("left") == "0px") {
        $('.span4').css("left", "auto");
    } else if ($('.span4').css("left") < "0px") {
        $('.span4').css('left', -$(window).scrollLeft() - 20);
    }
})
})();
$(function () {
$(window).resize(function () {

    if ($(window).width() >= "1130") {
    $('.span4').css("left", "auto");
    }
})
})();
```

All I've done it add "()" to the end of each function so that it invoked immediately. Worth a try.